# Filter rows of a file by list of a second file

Tags: text-processing

`file1.tabular` contains information of 'elements' over 3 columns.

```
element1 235 oval red \
element2 334 oval red \
element3 356 rectangular blue
```

`file2.txt` contains a single column

```
element1\
element3
```

I want to filter `file1.tabular` and save them as `file3.tabular`, which will contain only the elements in `file2.txt`, but with all 3 column information in `file1.tabular`, such as

```
element1 235 oval red\
element3 356 rectangular blue
```

Would there be an command to solve this on Ubuntu?
I would appreciate an expert help.
Thanks

Comment: Are the `\` at the ends of your lines really part of your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for

```
grep -f file2.txt file1.tabular > file3.tabular
```

The `-f` option instructs `grep` to read the patterns to look for from `file2.txt`. It applies the search to `file1.tabular` and redirects output to `file3.tabular`.

Note that I assume there are not really "line continuation" escapes ( the `\` at the end of all lines) in your files.

---

Note: As usual with regular expression-based searches, you need to be careful when formulating the content of `file2.txt`.

- Any characters special to RegExes that you want to be matched literally need escaping.
- Also, `grep` will by default show partial matches (i.e. one pattern matching only a sub-string of a word in `file1.tabular`). To alleviate, you can use the `-w` switch to allow only "full-word" matches.